# Launching ProtonVPN On Ubuntu 22.04 Error - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: networking, python, vpn

I am facing this issue using ProtonVPN on Ubuntu, it was working well a few days ago. I have also tried to reinstall it several times but nothing seems to work. Please if anyone got this before, here's the ouput :

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/protonvpn-app", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('proton-vpn-gtk-app==4.2.0', 'console_scripts', 'protonvpn-app')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/proton/vpn/app/gtk/__main__.py", line 34, in main
    controller = Controller.get(executor)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/proton/vpn/app/gtk/controller.py", line 56, in get
    executor.submit(controller.initialize_vpn_connector).result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 458, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 403, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/proton/vpn/app/gtk/controller.py", line 89, in initialize_vpn_connector
    self._connector = await self._api.get_vpn_connector()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/proton/vpn/core/api.py", line 54, in get_vpn_connector
    vpn_connector = await VPNConnector.get_instance(settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/proton/vpn/connection/vpnconnector.py", line 66, in get_instance
    await cls._instance.initialize_state(initial_state)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/proton/vpn/connection/vpnconnector.py", line 149, in initialize_state
    await self._update_state(state)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/proton/vpn/connection/vpnconnector.py", line 250, in _update_state
    new_event = await state_tasks
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/proton/vpn/connection/states.py", line 176, in run_tasks
    await self.context.kill_switch.disable()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/proton/vpn/killswitch/backend/linux/networkmanager/nmkillswitch.py", line 77, in disable
    await self._ks_handler.remove_full_killswitch_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/proton/vpn/killswitch/backend/linux/networkmanager/killswitch_connection_handler.py", line 202, in remove_full_killswitch_connection
    await self._remove_connection(_get_connection_id(permanent=False))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/proton/vpn/killswitch/backend/linux/networkmanager/killswitch_connection_handler.py", line 228, in _remove_connection
    await _wrap_future(self.nm_client.remove_connection_async(connection))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/proton/vpn/killswitch/backend/linux/networkmanager/nmclient.py", line 230, in remove_connection_async
    self._run_on_glib_loop_thread(_remove_connection_async).result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 458, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 403, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/proton/vpn/killswitch/backend/linux/networkmanager/nmclient.py", line 118, in wrapper
    future.set_result(function(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/proton/vpn/killswitch/backend/linux/networkmanager/nmclient.py", line 217, in _remove_connection_async
    handler_id = device.connect("state-changed", _on_interface_state_changed)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connect'```
````